# Question on the non-existence of a satisfaction formula in $\mathbb{L}$

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I know this may sound trivial, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the problem is. Let $\mathbb{L}$ be the class of constructible sets. We know that $(\mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}, \in)$ is a countable structure and that $\omega \in \mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}$. So we can build complex things involving $\omega$ and therefore code a lot of things inside $(\mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}, \in)$. Since every element of $\mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}$ can be obtained from some $\phi$ and some finite number of parameters, why can't we describe the whole construction of $\mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}$ inside $\mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}$ (at a finite level $\mathbb{L}_{\omega+n}$) resulting in a definition of a formula $\mathrm{Sat}$ that defines satisfiability in $\mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}$? Parameter $u$ from higher levels can be reduced to level $\mathbb{L}_{\omega}$, since $u = \{ x \in \mathbb{L}_{\omega+n} : \phi(x,\bar{v})\}$, where $\mathbb{L}_{\omega + n}$ and every $\bar{u}$ can be substituted by their defining formulas and finite number of parameters from lower levels (finitely many levels down). $\mathbb{L}_{\omega}$ can be defined using such formula also, so everything in $\mathbb{L}_{\omega + \omega}$ can be defined using parameters from $\mathbb{L}_{\omega}$. The same question holds for any structure though.

Comment: I'm not a specialist, but I think the problem is that you can't write a single formula to describe the construction. You'd need infinitely many formulas and infinitely many parameters, and that you can't do.

Comment: You don't need infinite formulas or parameters, since you can code infinite sequences in $\mathbb{L}_{\omega}$.

Comment: Even if you could encode an infinite sequence of parameters, you can't do that for formulas (of the metalanguage, in first order logic). The way we're talking about it, in purely abstract terms, it also seems to me that you can only code *definable* sequences. But if you could define the sequence you'd need to get $L_{\omega+\omega}$, you'd already be done. That's circular reasoning.

Comment: If you could carry the contruction of $L_{\omega+\omega}$ this would contradict Tarski's theorem on definition of truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't even construct $M$ in $L_{\omega+\omega}$ elementary equivalent to $L_{\omega+\omega}$ because of [Tarski's undefinability theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem):

We have that the set of hereditaly finite sets, $\mathsf {HF}$, is a subset of $L_{\omega+\omega}$. Let $T$ be the set of all sentences that $L_{\omega+\omega}$ satisfies. Now suppose there is some $M\in L_{\omega+\omega}$ such that $(M,\in)$ and $(L_{\omega+\omega},\in)$ are elementary equivalent, then as $\mathsf{HF}\subseteq L_{\omega+\omega}$ we can define in $L_{\omega+\omega}$ whether for any formula $\varphi(\bar x)$ and any $\bar a\in M$, $M\models\varphi(\bar a)$, thus as $M\in L_{\omega+n}$ for some $n<\omega$, we have that $T\in L_{\omega+n+1}$, contradicting Tarski's undefinability theorem.